# "The parameter is incorrect" error running Ant

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, tibco

We are implementing a solution of Invoking AppManage TIBCO commands from ANT script from Jenkins. Jenkins is responsible to download the source code from SVN and then execute the Ant script. Below is the snippet of the build.xml and also the error that i receive when invoking from Jenkins.

Error:

```
build [bin] $ cmd.exe /C "E:\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin\ant.bat -file build.xml 
-D=DEVENV -DVersion=tag3 -DDEVNAM="" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
The parameter is incorrect
ERROR: command execution failed.
```

The script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="tibco_test_client" basedir="." default="deploy.tibco">
<property name="projectName" value="tibco_test_client"/>
<property name="ear.dir" value="E:\CI\workspace\ear"/>
<property name="App.dir" value="TestApache/${projectName}"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="../lib"/>
<property name="tibco.tra.home" value="E:\esb\profile\ESB_SRV_01\1.1\product\tibco\tra\5.8\bin"/>
<property name="tibco.AppManage.path" value="E:\esb\profile\ESB_SRV_01\1.1\product\tibco\tra\5.8\bin\AppManage.exe"/>
<property name="tibco.domain" value="NAM_DEV_01"/>
<property name="tibco.user" value="namdev_admin"/>
<property name="tibco.password" value="NAMDev01"/>
<property name="Updated.xml.Path" value="E:\CI\workspace\${projectName}.xml"/>

<property name="propertyFile.Name" value="E:\CI\workspace\tibco_test_client.properties"/>
    <target name="clean.tibco" description="Delete all generated ear files">
    <delete dir="${ear.dir}" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="${ear.dir}"/>
</target>

 <target name="compile.tibco" depends="clean.tibco" description="Compiles BusinessWorks projects">
     <taskdef name="tibbwBuildEar" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.tibco.TibbwBuildEar" classpath="${jar.dir}/ant-tibco.jar"/>
     <tibbwBuildEar srcdir="E:\CI\workspace\${projectName}" destdir="${ear.dir}" bindir="${tibco.tra.home}">
     </tibbwBuildEar>
  </target>


<target name="config.tibco" depends="compile.tibco" description="Extracts the config file of BusinessWorks projects">
     <taskdef name="tibbwExportConfig" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.tibco.TibbwExportConfig" classpath="${jar.dir}/ant-tibco.jar"/>
     <tibbwExportConfig srcdir="${ear.dir}" destdir="${ear.dir}" bindir="${tibco.tra.home}">           
     </tibbwExportConfig>     
</target>

<target name="init" depends="config.tibco">        
    <property file="${propertyFile.Name}"/>
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
 </target>



 <target name="UpdateXML" description="update the generated XML configuration values based on  Property file values " depends="init">      
      <property file="${propertyFile.Name}" prefix="x"/>        
      <local name="propertyList"/> 
      <propertyselector property="propertyList" delimiter="," select="\1" match="x\.([^\.]*)\.xpath" casesensitive="true" distinct="true"/>

      <for list="${propertyList}" param="sequence">               
        <sequential>
           <echo> @{sequence} </echo>  
            <echo> @{sequence}.xpath = ${x.@{sequence}.xpath} </echo>
            <echo> @{sequence}.value = ${x.@{sequence}.value} </echo> 

         <xmltask dest="${Updated.xml.Path}">
         <fileset file="${Updated.xml.Path}"/>
         <replace 
            path="${x.@{sequence}.xpath}"
            withText="${x.@{sequence}.value}"/>
    </xmltask>

        </sequential>               
      </for>          
 </target> 


 <target name="deploy.tibco" depends="UpdateXML" description="Deploys the BusinessWorks ears">
     <taskdef name="tibbwDeploy" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.tibco.TibbwDeploy" classpath="${jar.dir}/ant-tibco.jar"/>
     <tibbwDeploy srcdir="${ear.dir}" bindir="${tibco.tra.home}" domain="${tibco.domain}" user="namdev_admin" password="NAMDev01">
     </tibbwDeploy>
  </target>


 <!--<target name="undeploy.tibco" depends="deploy.tibco" description="Undeploys the BusinessWorks ears">
     <taskdef name="tibbwUndeploy" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.tibco.TibbwUndeploy" classpath="${jar.dir}/ant-tibco.jar"/>

     <tibbwUndeploy srcdir="${ear.dir}" bindir="${tibco.tra.home}" domain="${tibco.domain}" user="namdev_admin" password="NAMDev01">         
     </tibbwUndeploy>

</target>

<target name="delete.tibco" depends="undeploy.tibco"  description="Deletes the BusinessWorks ears">
     <taskdef name="tibbwDelete" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.tibco.TibbwDelete" classpath="${jar.dir}/ant-tibco.jar"/>

     <tibbwDelete srcdir="${ear.dir}" bindir="${tibco.tra.home}" domain="${tibco.domain}" user="namdev_admin" password="NAMDev01">       
     </tibbwDelete> 

</target> -->

</project>
```

Comment: Can you please post more detailed error such which line of the script is leading to error? Is your operating system `windows`? Because, error message has `$` prompt.

Comment: Run the `ant` shell script with `sh` instead of the windows `cmd`.

Comment: Why not use an Ant build step in your Jenkins configuration?

Comment: This is windows system and this error occurs when invoking the ANT on the slave machine.

Comment: "Why not use an Ant build step in your Jenkins configuration?"...Where can this be added ??

Comment: You'll need to first install the Ant Plugin in your Jenkins server. Then "Invoke Ant" should become available in the "Add build step" menu of your Jenkins jobs.

Comment: This is what i have already done and its not able to invoke ANT script from Jenkins and gives the incorrect command error but the same command runs when i run it on Slave machine.

Comment: Anyone faced this similar issue ?